# Generate sourcemap without access to build process

Tags: javascript, source-maps

I have an external script that is minified and unfortunately I cannot access the build process to generate a sourcemap.

I do however have access to the unminified version of this script, but ideally I don't have to deploy that to track errors.

Are there any tools that can take the existing minified and unminifed code and generate a sourcemap?

Comment: I think is more easy create your own build process to generate both the minified version and the sourcemap.

Comment: @Pollin That may be an option in the future, but for the moment I'm required to include the external script.